# Import returns undefined when imported from another package

Tags: javascript, webpack, yarnpkg

I've a really strange bug. Imagine I have a repository setup with yarn workspaces that contains:

- theme
- ui
- addon-1
- addon-2

My `theme` package has an `index.js` file that exports components like this:

```
export { default as Markdown } from './components/markdown';
export { default as Image } from './components/image';
```

Markdown:

```
import { Display } from 'ui'
//...
```

Image:

```
import { Display } from 'ui'
//...
```

Now the interesting part. `addon-1` uses `import { Markdown } from 'theme'` and it works perfectly. `addon-2` uses `import { Image } from 'theme'` and the `Image` is loaded, but `Display`, or better said the whole `ui`, is now undefined. The same `ui` package is used in the `Markdown` where it's still available. It's the same package.. in the same node_modules folder. Whyyyy? I don't get it. Furthermore.. when I import `Image` via relative path from another component in the same package.. it works. I don't get it.

Does anybody have an idea?

I already tried resetting everything.. removing node_modules, removing yarn.lock, running `yarn cache clean`.. I even tried removing the export from the index.js and directly importing the Image via `import Image from 'theme/components/image'`. Switching from default to named export..

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved by trial and error.
My code was absolutely right, but I reexported things from another package before my imports.. I still don't know why but when I don't reexport them and instead import them directly from the other package it's working.